# coherent states phase-space topology

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cold-atoms

Quantum mechanics can be formulated in various different ways. One of these is the so called *phase space* formulation, where we use quasi-probability distribution functions. The most recognized is the Wigner function, but one may also encounter Husimi $Q$ function or Glauber-Sudarshan $P$ function, where we make use of overcompletness property of coherent states.

Phase space of coherent states associated with Heisenberg-Weyl Lie group is isomorphic to complex plane. However, different systems may posses symmetries of arbitrary Lie group (especially $\mathfrak{su}$) and phase space topology differing from the complex plane [Trimborn 1](http://aleph.physik.uni-kl.de/~korsch/papers/PhysRevA_77_043631.pdf), [Trimborn 2](http://aleph.physik.uni-kl.de/~korsch/papers/PRA_79_013608.pdf).

My question is specific for cold atom gases: If You make mean-field approximation of the Hamiltonian (quantum) with dynamical group $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is the "classical" phase space flat (like for complex plane) or curved? Is it possible to have chaos in two-dimensional systems with non-flat geometry  unlike [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem)?

Comment: What is your notion of *flatness* for the phase space?

Comment: non-compact topology of complex plane

Comment: Soo...you call any phase space that is not the complex plane with the usual topology *non-flat*?